# Scalatest Suites do not have detailed test status output

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

When I run the following simple test using sbt I get the output I would expect:

```scala
import org.scalatest.{FlatSpec, Matchers, Suites}

class TestSimple extends FlatSpec with Matchers {
  "a" should "do" in {
    Array(1,3) should equal (Array(1,2))
  }
}
```

Output:

```
[info] TestSimple:
[info] a
[info] - should do *** FAILED ***
[info]   Array(1, 3) did not equal Array(1, 2) (SimpleTest.scala:5)
[info] ScalaTest
[info] Run completed in 980 milliseconds.
[info] Total number of tests run: 1
[info] Suites: completed 1, aborted 0
[info] Tests: succeeded 0, failed 1, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
[info] *** 1 TEST FAILED ***
[error] Failed: Total 1, Failed 1, Errors 0, Passed 0
[error] Failed tests:
[error]         TestSimple
[error] (test:test) sbt.TestsFailedException: Tests unsuccessful
```

When the Test is included in a Suite and annotated with DoNotDiscover like so:

```scala
import org.scalatest.{DoNotDiscover, FlatSpec, Matchers, Suites}

class FullTestSuite extends Suites(new TestSimple)

@DoNotDiscover
class TestSimple extends FlatSpec with Matchers {
  "a" should "do" in {
    Array(1,3) should equal (Array(1,2))
  }
}
```

then the output does not include the per test success and failures but instead has just the overall results:

```
[info] ScalaTest
[info] Run completed in 975 milliseconds.
[info] Total number of tests run: 1
[info] Suites: completed 2, aborted 0
[info] Tests: succeeded 0, failed 1, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
[info] *** 1 TEST FAILED ***
[error] Failed: Total 1, Failed 1, Errors 0, Passed 0
[error] Failed tests:
[error]         FullTestSuite
[error] (test:test) sbt.TestsFailedException: Tests unsuccessful
```

How can I get run tests inside a Suites instance to output where and how they have failed?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are facing a bug [`#916`](https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/issues/916). You should also try version `>=3.0.0-M15` and provide your feedback to developers.